# Mac OSX terminal folder names with special characters

Tags: macos, shell, encoding, terminal

I recently switched to MAC OSX and have encountered a problem when creating directories in terminal that have special characters in them.

Basically what happens is this:

- When I create the directory `té$t` in `Finder` and copy a file in there I can access it both in terminal and Finder
- When I create the same directory té$t in terminal and put a file in there I can access it in terminal, in Finder I get an error that the file can't be found. When I rename in terminal the directory without the special characters I can access the file in Finder.

  ```
  :> locale
  LANG=
  LC_COLLATE="C"
  LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
  LC_MESSAGES="C"
  LC_MONETARY="C"
  LC_NUMERIC="C"
  LC_TIME="C"
  LC_ALL=
  ```

This has to be some sort of encoding thing, right?

UPDATE:

forget the $ but use only the é instead (or any other áìç, etc...). The folder is created, it's only that I can't access any files in there in Finder when its created within the terminal

Comment: By any chance is it creating the `té` folder instead? Or is no folder created?

Comment: To expand on cjc343's point: If you didn't single-quote or escape the `$` in the file name, the shell would treat it as a variable expansion of a putative variable `t`. So, you wouldn't have created the folder you think or put the file where you think.

Comment: Maybe the $ was a bad example from my part, sorry about that, lets forget the $ but use only the é instead (or any other áìç, etc...). The folder is created, it's only that I can't access any files in there in Finder when its created within the terminal.

Comment: Please show the commands used to create the folder, an ls of created folder & files, the error when you try to access the folder via Finder, how you access the folder via finder, the umask, the release of mac os x, the underlying file system (e.g. on a usb device?), Case sensitivity state of the file system… There are a lot of guesses that can be made, but not knowing *what* the failure is under Finder is kind of important

Comment: Depending on how you create the directory in the terminal (character encoding of the terminal itself, your locale, method of entering the name, etc), it's possible that you aren't creating the directory name you think you are. Keep in mind that HFS+ uses something like NFD to normalize names, so that `tést` should be stored as `te\0301st` (with `é` stored as e + combining acute accent).

Comment: In addition to what Petesh requested, show the output of `ls | hexdump -C` in the directory containing the folder you created, both ways.

Answer (score 4):

In unicode, accented characters like é can generally be represented in two different ways: "precomposed" as a single code point representing the accented letter, or "decomposed" as a series of code points representing the unaccented letter followed by a combining accent (or even more than one...). In the case of "é", its precomposed form would be U+00e9 = UTF-8 0xc3a9 = "Latin small letter e with acute accent", and its decomposed form would be U+0065 U+0301 = UTF-8 0x65cc81 = "Latin small letter e" + "combining acute accent".

When you type the filename into the terminal, you're typing it in precomposed form; but the Mac OS Extended filesystem stores filenames in decomposed form (with some exceptions that aren't relevant here). When you specify a filename with precomposed characters in it, the filesystem will decompose them for storage. Net result: when you try to use the file later, you're trying to access it with a name that's equivalent to -- but not identical to -- the file's actual name. Depending on exactly how you access it, the equivalency may or may not be handled right, so the file may or may not be found.

In general, the filesystem handles equivalencies like this right, but the shell and other programs don't know the details of filesystem encoding and hence get it wrong. So if the shell/other program simply passes the name to the filesystem code, it works, but if the shell/other program tries to figure out if the file exists itself, it'll fail. For example, `touch "tést"; [ -e "tést" ]` uses the filesystem to find out if "tést" exists, and will find it; but tab-completion of `té` is handled by the shell, and will fail. See [this apple.se question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them/10484).

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce your problem on my Mac, but I haven't gone juggling my locale in the way you have.

#### Terminal

```
$ mkdir weird
$ cd weird
$ mkdir naïve résumé touché
$ for d in *; do cp ../q7.c $d/$d.c; done
$ ls -l *
naïve:
total 8
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  990 Nov 19 07:30 naïve.c

résumé:
total 8
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  990 Nov 19 07:30 résumé.c

touché:
total 8
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  990 Nov 19 07:30 touché.c
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$
```

I happened to have some source in a file `q7.c` lying around; this created a series of 'accented' directories, each containing an accented file. The command line tools have no problems.

#### Finder

This is where I can only demonstrate with images, I think:

[image]

That should show Finder looking at the file `naïve.c` in the folder `naïve`.  I was able to click on the file in Finder and it ran XCode:

[image]

#### Suggestion

First, try setting your locale to `en_US.UTF-8` and see whether that makes any difference.

If, perchance, it does, then I'd hypothesize that you are creating file names using Latin 1, but Finder runs with UTF-8. The trouble is then that your file names are not valid UTF-8 file names. That could prevent Finder from working.

Here's a program that goes around trying to abuse the system:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[] = "\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC6";
    char file[] = "weird.c";

    /*
    C0 U+00C0 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
    C1 U+00C1 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
    C2 U+00C2 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX
    C3 U+00C3 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE
    C4 U+00C4 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
    C5 U+00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
    C6 U+00C6 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE
    */

    if (mkdir(name, 0755) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "mkdir(%s) failed\n", name);
        return(1);
    }
    char buffer[32];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s/%s.c", name, name);
    FILE *ofp = fopen(name, "w");
    if (ofp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen(%s) failed\n", buffer);
        return(1);
    }
    FILE *ifp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (ifp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen(%s) failed\n", file);
        return(1);
    }
    size_t nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ifp)) != 0)
        fwrite(buffer, 1, nbytes, ofp);
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    return 0;
}
```

As you probably know, bytes 0xC0 and 0xC1 can never appear in well-formed UTF-8.  The other bytes are legitimate start bytes for 2-byte UTF-8 characters, but the following bytes should always be in the range 0x80..0xAF.  Clearly, the names are not well-formed UTF-8.

```
Osiris JL: make weird
    gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror weird.c -o weird  
Osiris JL: ls -l
total 40
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  1629 Nov 19 07:54 makefile
drwxr-----  4 jleffler  staff   136 Nov 19 07:36 naïve
drwxr-----  4 jleffler  staff   136 Nov 19 07:36 résumé
drwxr-----  4 jleffler  staff   136 Nov 19 07:36 touché
-rwxr-----  1 jleffler  staff  9068 Nov 19 08:00 weird
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  1142 Nov 19 07:59 weird.c
drwxr-----  3 jleffler  staff   102 Nov 19 08:00 weird.dSYM
Osiris JL: ./weird
fopen(???????/???????.c) failed
Osiris JL: ls -l
total 40
drwxr-----  2 jleffler  staff    68 Nov 19 08:00 %C0%C1%C2%C3%C4%C5%C6
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  1629 Nov 19 07:54 makefile
drwxr-----  4 jleffler  staff   136 Nov 19 07:36 naïve
drwxr-----  4 jleffler  staff   136 Nov 19 07:36 résumé
drwxr-----  4 jleffler  staff   136 Nov 19 07:36 touché
-rwxr-----  1 jleffler  staff  9068 Nov 19 08:00 weird
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  1142 Nov 19 07:59 weird.c
drwxr-----  3 jleffler  staff   102 Nov 19 08:00 weird.dSYM
Osiris JL:  rmdir *C6
Osiris JL: ./weird 2>&1 | odx
0x0000: 66 6F 70 65 6E 28 C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 2F C0 C1   fopen(......./..
0x0010: C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 2E 63 29 20 66 61 69 6C 65 64 0A   ......c) failed.
0x0020:
Osiris JL:
```

So, I was able to create the directory, after a fashion, but I can remove it using `rmdir *C6`. The name is not what I'd expect. The file could not be created.

Comment: Kinda relevant: Under Windows 7 using Chrome that first directory listing looks wrong.  While copying and pasting them into this comment box the file names are correct however, so something is broken with windows/chrome/stackoverflow.

Comment: Good answer. For what it's worth, OP may not have juggled his locale at all. Terminal.app sets the locale to match the system settings, but OS X does not have as broad support for locales at the Unix level as it does in its high-level frameworks. If the system preferences are set to a locale without a match at the Unix level, you get what OP posted.